# Multiple Content Page Control Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, contentcontrol, pagecontrol

I've been searching on the web for a little while for a content control for Windows Phone 7 with multiple pages, where I would be able change content by changing the index, something like a PageControl or a TabControl, but without the tabs, but I had no luck.
The Idea is to give the user multiple views for the content, but I don't want to use the pivot since it will be inside a pivot item. It can't be scrollable.
I would give the user the view options, and the control would show the option he chose.

Does anyone know any kind of control that can do this kind of thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need that kind of control I've to dissapointed you there is no such a thing. Your option is write control for your own. you can make 1 page.xaml and multiple user controls and changed user control by their name which you can pass by url

Comment: I see, What would be the best approach to write a content control for this purpose? Write a control that would have multiple content controls?

Comment: You can make dynamically created content control which will generate data/forms from objects properties and custom attributes

Comment: It would be cool if I could change the index, and have items, like the itemcontrol have.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **UserControl** and just switch the views on that **single page**. You would have to plumb your own implementation you want. But the controls should be extensible enough for it to be have your own custom implementation there on how it will work.

I would also suggest to go to this [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx) and check the inheritance of UserControl.

More specifically, to make it easier for you check [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) to make it easy to switch content in a single page. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would rather implement my own control for this purpose, but I don't what would be the best approach...